# Jinja2 can't load html file with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, flask, jinja2

### Problem

- I would like to make responsive site, and reduce the duplicated code.
- I use JQuery innerWidth for checking window size.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    {% block jquery %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
　　　var width = window.innerWidth;
      if (width > 540) {
      $('#desktop').load('main.html');
      } else {
      $('#mobile').load('main.html');
      }
    });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}

    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="mobile">
       // Mobile //
      </div>
      
      <div id="desktop">
       // Desktop //
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

### Question

- Jinja2 can't load html file with JQuery, and show only 'null'.

### Development Environment

- Jinja2
- JQuery3.3.1

### Tried

- When I change Jinja2 to ordinary html file, it works fine

Does anybody have a solution for my problem?
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it.

```html
{% import "my_macro.html" as mm %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    {% block jquery %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
　　　var width = window.innerWidth;
      if (width > 540) {
        $("#mobile").html({{mm.main() | tojson}});
      } else {
        $("#desktop").html({{mm.main() | tojson}});
      }
    });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}

    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="mobile">
       // Mobile //
      </div>
      
      <div id="desktop">
       // Desktop //
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```